# Comportamento do foreach com variáveis por referência

Tags: php, foreach, referência

Estava fazendo alguns testes e percebi que o `foreach` apresenta um comportamento estranho.

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte `array`:

```
$array = array('primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro');
```

Quando eu executo um `foreach` usando uma referência, e em, seguida, um outro foreach sem referência (com a mesma variável), veja o que ocorre:

```
$array = array('primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro');

foreach ($array as &$b);

var_dump($array);

foreach ($array as $b);

var_dump($array);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'primeiro' (length=8)
  1 => string 'segundo' (length=7)
  2 => &string 'terceiro' (length=8)

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'primeiro' (length=8)
  1 => string 'segundo' (length=7)
  2 => &string 'segundo' (length=7)
```

Veja que o último elemento passou a ter o valor diferente.

Então surgiram duas perguntas:

- O último valor de `$array` passou a ter o valor do penúltimo elemento?
- Por que, após um `foreach` com variável por referência, o último elemento fica como referenciado pela variável (que fica depois do `as`)?

**Observação**: Reparem o sinal de `&` no resultado.

Comment: Tem uma discussão bacana no SO gringo sobre isso [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach)

Comment: Fazer uma pergunta criativa quando o objetivo, ao que me parece, é a própria construção da pergunta, é difícil mesmo. Perguntas que provém de problemas reais que o pessoal encontra, no geral, são muito mais produtivas e bem aceitas pela comunidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você "iguala" duas variáveis, você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras:

- **Por valor**: Indicando que *naquele ponto do código* o valor de uma é igual ao da outra:

  ```
  $a = $b;
  ```
- **Por referência**: Indicando que, até que seja dito o contrário, elas são iguais, ou seja, o que acontecer com uma deverá acontecer com a outra:

  ```
  $b = "b";
  $a = &$b;
  var_dump($a);   //Imprime: var 'b'

  $a = 'a';
  var_dump($b);   //Imprime: var 'a'
  ```

Ao passar a variável `$b` por referência no primeiro foreach, você está, a cada iterada, vinculando o valor de `$b` com uma posição do vetor `$array`.

```
$b = &$array[0];  //na primeira iterada
```

Ao estabelecer o vínculo com uma outra variável, o primeiro vínculo é quebrado, ou seja, na segunda iteração `$b` está vinculado com `$arrray[1]` e não mais com `$array[0]`. Em outras palavras, ao final do primeiro foreach, `$b` está vinculado à (e apenas à) terceira posição do vetor:

```
$b = &$array[2];  //na última iterada
```

No segundo foreach, a cada iterada, estamos dizendo que `$b` tem um novo valor e, logo, `$arrray[2]` também tem um novo valor a cada iterada. Na penúltima iterada fazemos:

```
$b = $array[1];
//o que implica que também estamos fazendo $array[2] = $array[1];
```

E por isso, quando chegamos na última iterada do segundo foreach, a última posição está com o valor da penúltima.

Comment: entendi. Só para complementar a pergunta: para isso não acontecer no segundo foreach, deveriamos simplesmente fazer um `unset($b)`