# Foreach por referência ou por valor?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

Existe alguma diferença em termos de desempenho e segurança entre usar o foreach por referência ou por valor? Eu sempre uso a primeira opção(quando necessário) por achar o código menos confuso de se ler.

### Referência:

Aqui eu troco todos os valores de uma array pela string `exemplo` utilizando passagem por referência.

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value = 'exemplo';
}
```

### Valor:

Aqui eu troco todos os valores de uma array pela string `exemplo` utilizando passagem por valor.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key]= 'exemplo';
}
```

### Exemplo:

Aqui está um exemplo de um código meu(com algumas linhas removidas para ficar mais fácil de entender) em que eu faço o que algumas respostas e comentários dizem que daria errado, mas não tenho erro nenhum:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    //Removida as linhas em que calculo alguns valores para a substr.
    $value['arq_descricao'] = substr($value['pes_texto'], $inicio, $tamanho);
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80815/comportamento-do-foreach-com-vari%C3%A1veis-por-refer%C3%AAncia

Comment: Por mais que as duas perguntas sejam sobre foreach, não acho que sejam parecidas.

Comment: "Relacionado" não é "duplicado". Em nenhum momento disse que eram parecidas. Sua pergunta recebeu votos para fechamento porque ela leva a resposta baseada em opiniões.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters desculpe, sou novo no site

Comment: A minha pergunta linkada já é um ponto para você evitar usar por referência, ou, se for usar, usar com cuidado.

Comment: Não há problemas, Guilherme. Você pode editar sua pergunta para ficar dentro do escopo e ser aceita. Acho que a pergunta em si aborta um tema bem interessante, mas o problema foi a pergunta final. Ela pediu opinião. Acho que querer saber a questão da segurança e desempenho não é ruim, mas a questão da legibilidade já é bem pessoal.

Comment: O cara ta perguntando sobre desempenho e boas práticas, esse link aí não tem nada a ver.

Comment: Se você não se importar, posso editar o último trecho para ela ficar dentro do escopo...

Comment: @PedroMorais é um ponto para ele evitar o uso, como eu disse anteriormente. E pra falar a verdade, sua resposta é que não respondeu nada. Comentei abaixo o motivo do negativo para mostrar que a respostas precisa ser melhorada.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Mas eu perguntei a opinião porque quero saber a resposta pessoal mesmo, é como perguntar se na sua opinião vale a pena usar `if` sem chaves. Uma das respostas com certeza seria relacionada a boas práticas e diria para sempre utilizar chaves no `if`.

Comment: "Boas práticas" é muito relativo. Esse é o problema. O que é bom pra mim, pode ser ruim pra você, entende... Por isso vou tentar dar uma resposta o máximo imparcial possível.

Comment: @GuilhermePressutto vou dar um +1, pois apesar de levar a opiniões, creio que alguns aspectos das perguntas são interessantes para levar a uma resposta não baseada em opiniões, mas que esclareça sobre as diferenças de um e outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Desempenho

Não sou um expert nesse assunto, mas posso garantir que o desempenho nesse caso não faça tanta diferença ao ponto de valer a penas escolher um ou outro por conta disso.

## Segurança - Entendendo o comportamento de um e outro

A única segurança que está em risco é a sua. Digo isso pois é necessário entender o comportamento das referências nesse caso.

Como foi respondido nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80815/comportamento-do-foreach-com-vari%C3%A1veis-por-refer%C3%AAncia) existe uma pequena variação, em relação ao que se é esperado de um foreach normal, em relação à variável passada por referência.

Resumindo: O último valor fica sempre referenciado, podendo te causar problemas se você sobrescrever o valor de `$value`.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value = $value . 'R$';
}

$value = null;
```

Isso geraria:

```
['1R$', '2R$', null]
```

Veja um exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/aeTRxg#comments)

Por isso depois de usar um `foreach` com referência, sempre é bom chamar `unset` na variável referenciada (depois do loop).

<sub>Não vou falar muito sobre isso aqui, pois a pergunta linkada tem bastante sobre o assunto.</sub>

Nesse caso, não estou dizendo pra você não fazer assim (eu já fiz algumas poucas vezes). Estou apenas alertando que é melhor você saber tudo sobre o assunto, para o que "você não sabe" te cause problemas.

Mas, observando que podem surgir um "novo comportamento" em relação ao primeiro `foreach` - e ao mesmo tempo, isso também pode afetar a legibilidade caso esqueça de tratar a variável da referência devidamente-, eu poderia pensar na sua segunda opção como sendo a melhor.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = $value . 'R$';
}
```

Porém é preciso saber se é necessário e se é sábio alterar o valor original do seu `array`. Se você tem certeza que não vai mais usar o `array` "original", então você pode fazer isso sem medo de ser feliz :p

**A desvantagem de referência com `foreach`**

Lembrando que também você tem uma desvantagem ao usar `foreach` com referência: Você só pode fazer loop com o `array` guardado em variáveis. Expressões arbitrárias não podem ser usadas com referência em algumas versões do PHP anteriores ao 5.5.

Exemplo:

```
// Certo:

$array = [];

foreach ([1, 2, 3, 4] as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = $value . 'R$';
}

// Errado: Isso vai gerar um erro caso use PHP 5.4

foreach ([1, 2, 3, 4] as $key => &$value) {
    $value = $value . 'R$';
}
```

Veja um pequeno [teste](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cf38ffbd4c258b63660e16495a3001329025550)

## Tire a sua própria conclusão

Não quero te dar uma opinião sobre o assunto, quero que você apenas entenda que fazer um foreach com referência e fazer uma reatribuição com as chaves do `foreach` pode parecer que é a mesma coisa, mas tecnicamente não é. Referências podem ser vilãs se não forem usadas com sabedoria. Da mesma forma sobrescrever um valor de um `array` pode não ser uma boa ideia se você quer manter os valores originais.

Estou te mostrando alguns pontos, pois essa coisa de "boas práticas" na verdade é bem pessoal. Sempre é melhor você saber o que está fazendo e saber usar na hora certa.

Comment: Por que acontece esse erro no seu mas não acontece no meu código? Vou editar a pergunta com o código em questão.

Comment: Tá com o `error_reporting` ativado?

Comment: @GuilhermePressutto vou editar a pergunta. Realmente, isso depende da versão do PHP.

Comment: Olhe a parte "Exemplo". Eu faço basicamente o que sua resposta e sua pergunta linkada dizem que daria errado, mas não da errado.

Comment: @GuilhermePressutto eu vi aqui, testei no http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/. O erro só ocorre com a versão 5.4 do PHP. Vou ver se a documentação fala algo a respeito, não me lembro de ter visto isso como "novas funcionalidades" quando o PHP 5.5 foi lançado.

Comment: Na verdade aqui na empresa trabalho com PHP 5.3.3-7.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46753/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-guilherme-pressutto).

Answer (score -1):

Se você realmente precisa da chave($key) você usa a segunda opção, pois as vezes eu preciso alterar o valor da variável, por exemplo:

```
$ar = ['a'=>'x','b'=>'y'];
    foreach($ar as $key => $value){
        $ar[$key] = $value+'alterado';
}
```

Agora se você não for alterar o valor do array pai($ar), nem use $key, o desempenho e a leitura são melhores (muda quase nada, mas são melhores)

Comment: -1 Isso não responde à pergunta. Poderia adicionar alguma explicação à resposta?

Comment: Você teve pelo menos o trabalho de ler a resposta toda ?

Comment: No seu caso eu usaria `foreach($ar as $key => &$value){ $value = $value.'alterado'; }`

Comment: Só tem código...

Comment: olhe a parte comentada

Comment: @PedroMorais eu editei a resposta...

Comment: Valeu, to com problemas em misturar código e texto nas respostas

Comment: Ok. Bem, eu acho que assim ficou melhor, mas ainda a explicação está um pouco vaga. Por  exemplo: "desempenho e leitura são melhores"... Baseado em quê? Você vez testes? Se fez, por favor adicione a resposta. Se é alguma fonte, favor adicionar o link da fonte.

Comment: Acho que esta discussão já pode ser encerrada. Ele respondeu que só vale a pena usar este código dele quando não tiver como usar outro e eu já comentei que da pra usar de outra forma sim.

Answer (score -1):

Quando você trabalha com valor você tem uma nova instância do array. Quando você trabalha com referência, você modifica o array original.

Basicamente, quando você utiliza o array por valor você tem uma cópia desse array válida apenas dentro do escopo do foreach, for, while e afins.

Execute o exemplo abaixo para ter uma ideia.

```
<?php

$array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

echo "Array original";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $v = $k;
}

echo "Array após foreach por valor";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
    $v = $k;
}

echo "Array após foreach por referência";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: "Quando você trabalha com referência você tem uma nova instância do array, no caso array. " poderia explicar isso? Quando você usa referência, você está trabalhando em cima do valor original do `array`. E eu acho que você se esqueceu do símbolo `&` antes da variável `$v`.

Comment: No exemplo, usando por referência, o array original permanece inalterado. Você faz alterações válidas apenas no escopo daquela estrutura de repetição.

Comment: Você não está usando a referência. Você está fazendo um foreach onde a cópia ocorre normalmente. O que foi perguntando foi outra coisa. Observe o código do primeiro exemplo da pergunta e vai ver que ele colocou o `&` (sinal de referência) lá.

Comment: Após corrigir a inversão, também fiz uma pequena alteração no código. Creio que agora esteja tudo correto.

Comment: Estou tentando entender de que forma isso responde à pergunta. Ele perguntou sobre performance, legibilidade e segurança, porém isso não foi citado na resposta...

Comment: Sua resposta é a minha pergunta, um pouco menos completa. Eu já disse isso que você respondeu na minha questão, e ainda coloquei como alterar o valor original mesmo quando se passa por valor.