# Utilização do Foreach no PHP

Tags: php, foreach

O construtor `foreach` fornece uma maneira fácil de iterar sobre **arrays**. Em diversos scripts podemos observar a seguinte utilização:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

No entanto, encontra-se em alguns casos a seguinte utilização:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

O que exatamente seria o carácter `&` acompanhado da variável `$value`, e qual seu efeito dentro do comando `foreach`?

Comment: & significa que você está utilizando a referência. Assim $value possui uma referencia a uma posição do seu array, alterando $value o valor é alterado na posição do seu array automaticamente.

Comment: Exemplo nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158546/57801

Comment: Se no foreach sem referência, eu modificar o valor de $value, eu não vou estar alterando o valor dentro do array?

Comment: Não, você precisará atribuir novamente para o array, senao a alteração fica apenas na variável enquanto ela existir no ciclo, quando o ciclo for finalizado a alteração é perdida e no novo ciclo é atribuído a próxima posição do array.

Comment: Documentação do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: No caso a seguir, eu realizo alterações sem a referência e elas se mantem, veja: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee080b3cf307eb359545e8d6594f32d6a208acf6

Comment: É o mesmo principio da referência, você está instanciando uma classe e colocando ela dentro de um array, porém as classes trabalham diretamente com referencia. Assim, se você alterar algum atributo da classe, todos os lugares que tiverem a referência dessa classe serão alterados também. Um exemplo é [esse aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be707e3b92448c5ce26c56dda7e98edeb74054ec), criei uma classe e atribui a 2 variáveis, alterando o valor em uma delas vai alterar na outra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A utilização da segunda maneira é referente a passagem por referência, ou seja, se você alterar o valor que contém em `$value` vai alterar na posição de memória referente a posição do array que está sendo percorrido.

Para entender melhor:

**O que as referências fazem**

Referências no PHP permitem criar duas ou mais variáveis que se referem ao mesmo conteúdo. Ou seja, quando você faz:

```
<?php
$a =& $b;
?>
```

então aqui `$a` e `$b` apontam para o mesmo conteúdo. Alterando qualquer uma das duas variáveis o conteúdo é alterado automaticamente na outra, pois estão vinculadas a mesma posição de memória.

[Fonte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php)

Deve-se verificar se há algum problema no desempenho, há um tópico sobre isso

[Foreach por referência ou por valor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158546/foreach-por-refer%C3%AAncia-ou-por-valor)

Referente ao [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213281/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-foreach-no-php#comment436019_213281), nesse caso você está alterando o valor de uma classe e não de um valor no array.

Ao alterar o atributo da classe será alterado onde estiver todas as instâncias dela.

Exemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be707e3b92448c5ce26c56dda7e98edeb74054ec